# Bind dynamic Json data in pie chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts and want to bind dynamic json data to pie chart.Here is my dynamic string

```
for(i = 0; i < month.length; i++){
    pi_data+='{name:"'+month[i]+'",y: '+ percent[i] +',color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors['+ i 
 +']},';
}
```

Here i am generate json string and bind in pie chart data option below

```
{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Total Percentage',
    data: [pi_data],
    center: [100, 50],
    size: 100,
    showInLegend: false,
}
```

My return string is

{name:"January",y: 24.78,color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]},{name:"February",y: 14.69,color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]},{name:"March",y: 26.51,color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]},{name:"April",y: 34.01,color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]}

If i put directly in data option it working but if i put variable in data option(inside [ ] in data:) it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are formatting the data is incorrect. `data` parameter takes an array of items, where as here your passing is an object.

Try converting it to the following format:

```
let pi_data = month.map((item,index) => ({
    name: item.month,
    y: item.percent,
    color:  Highcharts.getOptions().colors[index]
}));

//Result
[
    { name: "January", y: 24.78, color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] },
    { name: "February", y: 14.69 , color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]},
    { name: "March", y: 26.51,color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] },
    { name: "April", y: 34.01,color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3] }
  ]
```

And in the options just have this array placed

```
{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Total Percentage',
    data: pi_data,
    center: [100, 50],
    size: 100,
    showInLegend: false,
}
```

Fiddle for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/vo3ch9L1/

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want `data` to be an array, not a string of JS code (what you get from the loop; it's also malformed), so you need to compose `pi_data` properly. Try this:

```js
// From the loop I assumed pi_data should be an array.
let pi_data = []

for(i = 0; i < month.length; i++){
    pi_data.push({
        name: month[i],
        y: percent[i],
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
    });
}

{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Total Percentage',
    data: pi_data, // No []!
    center: [100, 50],
    size: 100,
    showInLegend: false,
}
```